# Error using Join on uniqueidentifier - convert uniqueidentifier to numeric

Tags: nhibernate, join, sql-server-ce, fluent

I am using Fluent NHibernate on sqlserverce.
Using NHibernate QueryOver I try to retrieve a row  - NHibernate generate automatically a a join query
and I get the following Exception:

```
[SQL: SELECT tag FROM CheckpointToProtectionGroup cp2pg 
      JOIN CheckpointStorageObject cp ON cp.id = cp2pg.checkpoint_id 
      JOIN ProtectionGroupCheckpointStorageObject pg ON pg.id = cp2pg.vpg_id 
      WHERE cp.CheckpointIdentifierIdentifier = 1111  AND 
            pg.ProtectionGroupIdentifierGroupGuid = 
               11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111]
---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: 
     The conversion is not supported. 
     [ Type to convert from (if known) = uniqueidentifier, 
       Type to convert to (if known) = numeric ]
```

From what I see, it seems that it tries to convert the value - 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 to numeric but this value is a Guid field:

```
CheckpointToProtectionGroup checkpointToProtectionGroup = Session
            .QueryOver<CheckpointToProtectionGroup>()
            .JoinQueryOver( row => row.ProtectionGroup)
            .Where(row => row.ProtectionGroupIdentifier.GroupGuid == 
                   protectionGroupIdentifier.GroupGuid)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

ProtectionGroupIdentifier.GroupGuid is of Guid type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `GroupGuid` value is not correctly converted to SQL. It should have single quotes around the value.

```
pg.ProtectionGroupIndentifierGroupGuidId = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
```

SQL Server tried to convert left hand value from `uniqueidentifier` (`Guid`) to `numeric`, since the right hand value is `numeric` value - numeric subtract operation with few operands.

You have `protectionGroupIdentifier.GroupGuid` value in `Where` part of your QueryOver expression. Check if `GroupGuid` is indeed `Guid` property. If it's an `object` property, cast it to `Guid`.

Comment: GroupGuid is Guid Property. but NHibernate don't figure it when I use JoinQueryOver. When QueryOver is activated on GroupGuid entity (ProtectionGroupCheckpointStorageObject) Nhibernate provides correct SQL with GroupGuid of type Guid - [Type: Guid (0)]

Comment: It looks like a bug in NHibernate: When using a JoinQueryOver between 2 tables, NHibernate fail to convert simple Guid value to uniqueidentifier. Need your advice. Thanks

Comment: Is ProtectionGroupIdentifier another entity, or a custom type, or component? Maybe the problem is with that.

Comment: ProtectionGroupIdentifier is a component.

Comment: Hm, how about converting both sides to string in Where? Or just one and using Equals instead of ==. Not really sure if it will work. Maybe this wouldn't be a problem if you had a regular Guid property instead of component... I'm kind of out of ideas, so just trowing anything in.